# How to convert data from $resource?

Tags: angularjs, resources

I have url that return me `{"username":"x"}`.I make a get in angular using $resource and i obtain something like this:

[image]

How can i access the username field?
Here is my code for angular factory:

```
app.factory('User', function ($resource) {
return $resource('https://damp-harbor-4220.herokuapp.com/auth/users/:id', {},
  {
    query: {
      method:'GET',
      params:{},
      isArray:false,
      transformResponse:[]
    }
  });
```

})

And in controller:

```
var myUser=User.get({id:id1},{ 'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:false,params:{},transformResponse:function(data,headers){
                                            console.log(data);
                                            return data;
                                        }}})
                                        //var x=JSON.stringify(myUser);
                                        //var y=JSON.parse(x);
                                        console.log(myUser);
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Mathew's answer is basically correct, but .success is depracated. I'd change the code to:

Promises resolve with the data in a .success/.then function. So in order to do what you like you have to do this:

```
User.get({
    id : id1
}, {
    'query' : {
        method : 'GET',
        isArray : false,
        params : {},
        transformResponse : function (data, headers) {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        }
    }
}).then( 
       function(data) {console.log(data);},
       function(error) {console.log(error);} 
)
```

Comment: Another ideas? I don't understand why i have in the first two lines an object and after that i see data from server...

Comment: User.get(...).$promise.then()